# CouchDB Field Query in Array

Tags: json, mongodb, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, couchdb-2.0

Suppose I want to query all the `place_name` which are in United State. What should be my query or fields?

Here i have pasted my query down which gives me only first index but I want to get all the data. What should be my query then.

```
{
      "post_code": 35801,
      "country": "United States",
      "country_abbreviation": "US",
      "places": [
        {
          "place_name": "Huntsville",
          "longitude": -86.5673,
          "state": "Alabama",
          "state_abbreviation": "AL",
          "latitude": 34.7269
        },
{
          "place_name": "Huntsville12345",
          "longitude": -86.5673,
          "state": "Alabama",
          "state_abbreviation": "AL",
          "latitude": 34.7269
        }
      ]
    },
```

Present query is

```
"selector": {
    "places.0.place_name": {
        "$gte": null
      }

  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "places.0.place_name"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "places.0.place_name": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of query, you should use views.

You could create a view that map the following key: `[country,place_name]`

Map function eg:

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.places){
    for(var i in doc.places){
      emit([doc.country,doc.places[i].place_name);
    }
  }
}
```

This let you query: the list of countries and the list of places per country.

If you want the list of countries, you can use the following parameters in your query: `group_level=1&group=true`

If you want to get the places of the united states: `startkey=['United states']`